# How to extract the matrix to a submatrix

Tags: r, matrix, extract

New to R, it might be a stupid question but I just have no thoughts.
I am doing the social network analysis and one of the works is to extract the entries that appeared in the same waves, i.e. t1t2 or t2t3.

I got a mega matrix file [mega matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vc195.png) and tried to get the right entries according to a list.
[list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddutV.png)

Should I use dplyr or write if-then condition? or what kinds of function?
Hope someone gives me a hint, thanks in advance!!

Comment: Please add data using `dput` or something that we can copy and use. Also show expected output for the data shared. Read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: The question is not clear as to which column, row of megamatrix you want to extract.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to extract rows which `t1t2Node` (the object you refer to as "a list") is equal to 1, then simply:

```
indexes <- as.logical(my_list)
filtered_matrix <- mega_matrix[indexes, ]
```